# Handle Hyperlink Click Event in Outlook Mail in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I want to handle the hyperlink click event in an outlook mail. To open the hyperlinks in outlook mails without opening the browser within itself.

Does anyone know  how to handle hyperlink click event on a mail item?

Comment: Interesting question. I don’t know whether such an event exists in the object model though…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found that there is no way to catch the hyperlink click event in outlook.

If we want to catch a link we can define our own protocol url as follow.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Then using our own protocol handler we can catch the event.

If someone needs more information ask here.

Comment: Hi @MoraRockey! Can you catch the event inside your AddIn or only call  a external programm? Also Does this work for only IE or all webBrowsers?

Comment: This question still lingers in 2018.. if anyone can come up with an example to catch link events _integrated_ in the Addin it has big potential in security aspects.

Answer (score -2):

Write an Outlook Add-in .net to handle that. To get the basic idea about writing an add- in  look at the following link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I know how to write an add-in. I want to know when a hyperlink is clicked.