# Call outlook macro using vbscript or Email Hyper links

Tags: html, vba, vbscript, outlook

I'm trying to call an outlook procedure from VBScript.
Bellow is my VBScript code (its not working)

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
objOutlook.run "Call_outlook_macro"
objOutlook.Quit
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

Please help me.

EDIT:
Basically, I wanted to call outlook macro by clicking a hyper link (using HTML tags and href, I'm not very good with HTML) in incoming mail(this will be sent from servers). But I couldn't find a way to use hyperlinks to call macros.
The work around to this was to create a VBScript to call the outlook macro. I can easily fire a VBscript using a hyper link.
Also, the outlook macro I'm trying to call eventually opens up an outlook form.

If there's a way I can fire outlook macro using hyperlink in the mails, that would be great.

Comment: What error message are you getting. You need to provide more details.

Comment: I'm getting no error messages. Looks like the VBScript code is working but it's not calling the outlook macro for  some reason.

Comment: What should happen when a link is clicked?

Comment: It should call a macro in outlook, which is actually to open a form.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
objOutlook.mySub()
```

instead of `objOutlook.Run "Call_outlook_macro"` like suggested [here](http://www.code-tips.com/2009/03/microsoft-outlook-calling-vba-class.html).

`mySub`has to be in `ThisOutlookSession module`.

What is your `Outlook` version? This will not work with all versions [how-to-call-vba-macro-from-vbscript-in-outlook-2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc86869e-6e53-46ab-bb50-840027256a5d/how-to-call-vba-macro-from-vbscript-in-outlook-2010-without-changing-my-corporate-office-2010?forum=outlookdev).

If you can't call a procedure, you can adapt the sub to `VBScript` and use it directly, instead of calling it from `Outlook`.

Alternative: write an `Add-In` like suggested here [handle-hyperlink-click-event-in-outlook-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925891/handle-hyperlink-click-event-in-outlook-mail-in-c-sharp).

Alternative 2: Open form with javascript as suggested here [To launch a custom Outlook form from a Web page](http://www.outlookcode.com/d/code/formonweb.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work :(
I'm using Outlook 2013

Comment: See my edit and code whatever your procedure does in the `VBScript`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to call a VBA macro from message bodies (hyperlinks). A new Outlook form is shown because you create a new Outlook Application instance:

```
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Try to use the GetObject or GetActiveObject functions instead, see [GetObject or GetActiveObject cannot find a running Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238610) for more information.